# Is it possible to block search engine indexing using DNS alone?

Tags: seo, dns, web-crawlers

As per the title, is it possible to block all search engine indexing using DNS? Most guides point towards `robots.txt` or `meta` headers but I'd like to investigate the possibility of blocking all indexing for a domain that will host all of our QA sites (which we don't want appearing on search engines).

Answer (score 3):

**No.** A DNS is a simple mechanism, you give it a domain, it returns an A-record (with the targetserver's IP address). There isn't really anything you can do.

Even *if* you manage to create a check in the DNS record, or add a meta tag with robots info, or create a robots.txt, they don't have to listen to it. They're simply being polite and respect the `robots.txt`, but there is no technical obligation for them to do so.

If they change the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` or a `X-ROBOTS` request-header info your check will no longer work. Or when you have an IP check and they switch to a new/unknown IP addrress, your check no longer works.

This is why I prefer to see these are *guides* for crawlers, not as rules.
Always assume that everything a visitor can see, can been seen by a crawler, one way or another. From a security perspective, this is safer.

Comment: What do you mean by, "If the crawler just changes its header info, or crawls from a new IP address, your check will not work."? What "check" is that?

Comment: Updated, more clear like this?

Comment: Sorry, still not sure what you mean? There shouldn't need to be any "check" that the OP/site needs to make regarding the request? What does it matter if the crawler changes the request headers (to pretend to be a regular visitor)?

Comment: Most robots respect your robots.txt but there is absolutely nothing to stop them if they decide to ignore it (or a meta tag, or a dns-check, or whatever check). Even if you block an IP, if they go to a new/unknown IP address, you can start all over.

Comment: Ah OK, I see what you're saying. But yeah, DNS doesn't work like that; it's a simple one-way lookup. But neither would you want/need to perform a conditional check like that (the user-agent either respects the response or not). (What's a `X-ROBOTS` request-header?) If you did need to go so far as requiring a "check", then it should probably be password protected.

Comment: That's like saying that a burgler doesn't have to respect your property line.  There's a difference between just sensing vs going inside, replicating everything, and then selling replicas commercially.  Also, making people build "robots.txt" is kind of awful considering that "robot" is derivative of a word for "slave".

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't block indexing using DNS - unless you made your site inaccessible! If there was a DNS method (like some kind of `txt` record or something) then the search engine would need to make a secondary lookup to find it.

If you need to block an entire domain, then look at the `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP response header (HTTP equivalent of the robots `meta` tag). Although most people will just block crawling with `robots.txt` (although note that this doesn't necessarily prevent indexing if the blocked resource gets linked to).

Comment: TXT records was the way I was expecting to be able to do it, if it indeed existed. That `X-Robots-Tag` header looks interesting, thanks for that info.